# Radial Basic function decision boundary

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am using radial basic function(rbf) in neural network using "newrb" method in Matlab and all things are good, but i hope to find a way which makes me able to draw the decisions boundary between the two samples that i have. For example in perceptron the decision boundary is a line with equation WX+b=0
W:weights, X:Inputs and b is the bias.How can i draw the complex decision boundary result from rbf?
Thanks. Hani Almousli.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is...   w*phi(x)     for the simplest single input, single function network

where.. w=wieght, phi=bias_function, x=input

Answer (score 0):

in matlab there 2 codes for plot the relation between input and target and decision boundary

> > plotpv(input,target)
> >
> > plotpc(weight,bias) for decision boundary

I hope that help